# Username length here compared to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, user-accounts

Not that it really bothers me that much, but on SO my username is 'SW', so, 2 characters.
If I try the same here I have to have 3 characters. Can I change this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's by design. Any new usernames must be three characters or more. So cherish that rare two character name on Stack Overflow.

See: [Prevent (or at least notify about) display names shorter than 3 chars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45241/prevent-or-at-least-notify-about-display-names-shorter-than-3-chars/50693#50693)